# Wordpress url parameter "country" on every page

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I would like to use a custom URL parameter for my wordpress site, called country.
This parameter should only be used internally.
For translation I use WPML. I know that it would be possible to create a language for every country / language combination but then I would have to maintain the same language for so many countries and that would be too much effort.

Anybody got an idea how I can make the url look something like that?

`www.my-domain.com/de/at` -> front page

`www.my-domain.com/de/at/my-post` -> other page

```
add_action('init', 'rewritecustom');
function rewritecustom(){
  add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)', 'country=');
  add_rewrite_tag('%lang%', '([^&]+)', 'lang=');
  add_rewrite_rule(
  '^([a-z]{2})\/([a-z]{2})\/([^\/]*)',
  'index.php?pagename=$matches[3]&country=$matches[2]&lang=$matches[1]',
  'top'
  );
}
```

In the permalink settings I set the url to

```
https://www.my-domain.com/%lang%/%country%/%postname%/
```

But unfortunately I get a 404 error when I try this.

Anybody got an idea how to solve it?